# How can I return the POST response object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and am trying to get a response that is returned when I do a post request.
This is what I have tried,but instead of returning the ReservationResponse Object, it returns this message "Instance of ReservationResponse" . What could I be doing wrong and how can I correct this?

```js
Future < dynamic > priceReservation(priceReservation) async {
  var content = jsonEncode(priceReservation.toJson());
  const baseUrl = ApiEndPoint.baseUrl;
  searchUrl = '$baseUrl/reservation/price';
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    body: content,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  final data = json.decode(response.body);
  ReservationResponse responseObject;
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    responseObject = ReservationResponse.fromJson(data);
    // print(data);
    print(responseObject); // it returns an "Instance of the ReservationResponse" object instead of the actual response
    return responseObject;
  } else
    return null;
}
```

```js
// My Class looks like this
@JsonSerializable()
class ReservationResponse {
  String ? id;
  String ? email;
  int ? quantity;
  int ? nights;
  double ? totalPricePerRoomPerNight;
  TotalPrice ? totalPrice;
  Room ? room;
  DateTime ? checkInDate;
  DateTime ? checkOutDate;
  List ? taxes = [];
  List ? discounts = [];

  ReservationResponse({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.quantity,
    this.nights,
    this.totalPricePerRoomPerNight,
    this.totalPrice,
    this.room,
    this.checkInDate,
    this.checkOutDate,
    this.taxes,
    this.discounts,
  });
  factory ReservationResponse.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) =>
    _$ReservationResponseFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$ReservationResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the toString() method when printing a class. Did you override the .toString() method in your custom class? If not, do this

```
@overide
toString(){
   return 'This is a string of my class. $someData'; //then implement what data the should be returned like this 
}
```

In the ReservationResponse class that you created, include the code above and input the data you want to show. Like this:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class ReservationResponse {
  String ? id;
  String ? email;
  int ? quantity;
  int ? nights;
  double ? totalPricePerRoomPerNight;
  TotalPrice ? totalPrice;
  Room ? room;
  DateTime ? checkInDate;
  DateTime ? checkOutDate;
  List ? taxes = [];
  List ? discounts = [];

  ReservationResponse({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.quantity,
    this.nights,
    this.totalPricePerRoomPerNight,
    this.totalPrice,
    this.room,
    this.checkInDate,
    this.checkOutDate,
    this.taxes,
    this.discounts,
  });
  factory ReservationResponse.fromJson(Map < String, dynamic > json) =>
    _$ReservationResponseFromJson(json);
  Map < String, dynamic > toJson() => _$ReservationResponseToJson(this);

  @override
  toString(){
    String output = 'ReservationResponse: id: ${this.id}, email: 
    ${this.email}'; //and so on for the info you want to return
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: But how I can do this, am just learning flutter and am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the class ReservationResponse , but now I don't understand, should I wrap my properties in the toString() method as you are suggesting?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: 'weird', the stringify solution worked, however let me ask, does this mean dart only works with strings? is stringify really the best solution?

Comment: Don't mix things up. My answer is the solution to get meaningful data when you try to print your custom class instead of getting the 'Instance of CustomClass' in the console, and that is exactly what toString() is for. If you need to access any other type of info from your class, you need to define another method to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I needed the Map response, so instead of stringifying the **responseObject** class, I just returned it's Map like this:

```js
Future < dynamic > priceReservation(priceReservation) async {
  var content = jsonEncode(priceReservation.toJson());
  const baseUrl = ApiEndPoint.baseUrl;
  searchUrl = '$baseUrl/reservation/price';
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(searchUrl),
    body: content,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
  );
  final data = json.decode(response.body);
  // ReservationResponse responseObject; replace with the map below
  Map < String, dynamic > ? responseObject;
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // responseObject = ReservationResponse.fromJson(data);
    responseObject = data;
    print(responseObject); // returns the Map response
    return responseObject;
  } else
    return null;
}
```